# AlertDialog does not show text

Tags: java, display

I am using `alertDialog` with switch case, I want the text to change depending on the case value.

here is the code that I tried :

```
private void transacechouée(int i) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Information")
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CashActivity1.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            ReadCardFragment.alertDialogBuilder=alertDialogBuilder;


        }
    });

    switch (i){
        case 1 :
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Transaction non aboutie");

            break;
        case 2:
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Connexion impossible");

            break;
        case 3:

            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Problème de récéption");
            break;
        case 4:

            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Erreur de traitement");
            break;
        case 5:

            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Erreur de transmission");


            break;
        case 6:
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Timout");
            break;
        case 7:

            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Transaction invalide");

            break;
        case 90:
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Piste non valide");

            break;
        case 91:

            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Transaction non valide");
            break;
            }


 }
```

I expect the `alertDialog` to set the message depending on the case, but it doesn't display any text.

Comment: Try to set the message on the `AlertDialog` object, not on the `AlertDialog.Builder` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calls to `setMessage` to occur before the dialog is actually shown.  Remember that the `AlertDialog.Builder` just builds the `AlertDialog`, using all the details that you've given it.  Calling the methods of `AlertDialog.Builder` after the `AlertDialog` has already been created is too late.

Move the whole `switch/case` structure that you've got upwards, to just before the line `AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();`.